# Using checklist in Bash file

Tags: bash

I want to create a bash script that do the following:

Create a project folder based on Project -- Name this is OK.

Create some folders based on user choices --This is the main question

Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash       
if [ ! -d /home/latreche/wienlaid ]; then
    mkdir -p /home/latreche/wienlaid;
fi;

cd /home/latreche/wienlaid
echo -n "Project Name:"
read pn
dir2=`eval echo $dir1`
mkdir $pn
mkdir $pn/optimization
mkdir $pn/optimization/$pn
mkdir $pn/scf
mkdir $pn/scf/$pn
```

Here is the user input section

```
echo "Do you wish to calculate elastic properties?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
    Yes ) mkdir $pn/elastic;mkdir $pn/elastic/$pn ;break;;
    No ) exit;;
    esac
done

echo "Do you wish to calculate band properties?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
    Yes ) mkdir $pn/band;mkdir $pn/band/$pn ;break;;
    No ) exit;;
    esac
done

echo "Do you wish to calculate DOS properties?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
    Yes ) mkdir $pn/dos;mkdir $pn/dos/$pn ;break;;
    No ) exit;;
    esac
done

echo "Do you wish to calculate Electronic Desnity properties?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
    Yes ) mkdir $pn/eldensity;mkdir $pn/eldensity/$pn ;break;;
    No ) exit;;
    esac
done

echo "Do you wish to calculate Optical properties?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
    Yes ) mkdir $pn/optic;mkdir $pn/optic/$pn ;break;;
    No ) exit;;
    esac
done

echo "Do you wish to use Hubbard DFT+U correction?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
    Yes ) mkdir $pn/$pn+"U";mkdir $pn/$pn+"U"/$pn ;break;;
    No ) exit;;
    esac
done

echo "Do you wish to use mBj correction?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
    Yes ) mkdir $pn/mbj;mkdir $pn/mbj/$pn ;break;;
    No ) exit;;
    esac
done

echo "Do you wish to Antiferromagnetic calculation?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
    Yes ) mkdir $pn/antiferro;mkdir $pn/antiferro/$pn ;break;;
    No ) exit;;
    esac
done
```

This is working OK but there is a lot of repetition and waste of time.

I wanted to do the above tasks using a checklist so i have tried this

```
DISTROS=$(whiptail --title "Do you want to" --checklist \
"Do you want to" 15 60 4 \
"AFM" "Do Antiferromagnetic calculation" OFF \
"SO" "Include Spin Orbital correction" ON \
"mBj" "Do mBj correction" OFF \
"DFT+U" "Do DFT+U calculation" ON \
"Elastic" "Calculate Elatic properties" OFF 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)

exitstatus=$?
if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]; then
    echo "Your favorite distros are:" $DISTROS
else
    echo "You chose Cancel."
fi
```

The last code is not doing what i want because i do not know how to retrieve decision data from it and use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`whiptail`'s `--separate-output` option](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/whiptail.1), it might be easier to work with:

```
--separate-output
      For checklist widgets, output result one line at a time, with no
      quoting.  This facilitates parsing by another program.
```

Secondly, from looking at your original `select`-based script, it seems to me that:

1. You have a folder name for each selection (`antiferro` for Antiferromagnetic, `$pn+U` for DFT+U, etc.).
2. For any choice, your actions are always:

   ```
   mkdir $pn/<folder-name>
   mkdir $pn/<folder-name>/$pn
   ```

You can simplify your script considerably by making these foldernames the output of `whiptail`. Instead of `mBj` which you use currently, for example, use `mbj` as the tag.

Then you can do:

```
whiptail --title "Do you want to" --checklist --separate-output \
    "Do you want to" 15 60 8 \
    "elastic" "Calculate Elastic properties" OFF \
    "band" "Calculate band properties" OFF \
    "dos" "Calculate band properties" OFF \
    "eldensity" "Calculate Electronic Density properties" OFF \
    "optic" "Calculate Optical properties" OFF \
    "$pn+U" "Do DFT+U calculation" ON \
    "mbj" "Do mBj correction" OFF \
    "antiferro" "Do Antiferromagnetic calculation" OFF \
    3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 |
    while read choice
    do
        mkdir "$pn/$choice/$pn" -p
    done
```

And you can use `mkdir`'s `-p` option:

```
-p, --parents
  no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```